# How to consume a rest web service in phonegap for android?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, web-services, cordova

I am a newbie in phone gap and trying to call a rest web service created in php with post parameters in **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** in my phone gap android app but not getting the response. Following is the code for calling the service:

```
     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "URL.php",
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(response) {
                    var resp = response.responseText;
                    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(resp);
                    console.log("Success: " + jsonObj);
                    },
                    error: function(request, status, error) {
                    console.log("Error status " + status);
                    console.log("Error request status text: " + request.statusText);
                    console.log("Error request status: " + request.status);
                    console.log("Error request response text: " + request.responseText);
                    console.log("Error response header: " + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
                    }
            });
```

I am getting [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u", source: file:///android_asset/www/a.html (1).

Please suggest me if there is any good tutorial/example available.

Thanks!!!

Comment: remove dataType parameter and try

Comment: No Sir, its still showing error message - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"

Comment: Can u post the error details you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o this error is not related to ajax check your syntax it is syntax error

Comment: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u", source: file:///android_asset/www/a.html (1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get it done!

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.url.php",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(response) {

                //entered in the success block means our service call is succeeded properly

                    var resp = JSON.stringify(response.text); // we are accessing the text from the json object(response) and then converting it in to the string format 
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); // print the response in console
                    alert(resp); // alert the response

                },
                error: function(request, status, error) {
                console.log("Error status " + status);
                console.log("Error request status text: " + request.statusText);
                console.log("Error request status: " + request.status);
                console.log("Error request response text: " + request.responseText);
                console.log("Error response header: " + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing and application in Phonegap just ,print the response in a div tag in the page instead of using Console . For How to send a request using jquery you can view the example given here:
http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/